# how to align all objects on the same line

Tags: html, css

i was trying border radius shapes but the circle shape isn't on the same line as the rest, is that normal? and how can i put it on the same line

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Kamy7/pen/GREQWrW

edit: that's the html i forgot
i have to type more words to save it lol

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <p class="rounded-edges">Rounded Edges</p>
    <p class="circle-shape">Circle Shape</p>
    <p class="top-bottom">Rounded top, bottom</p>
    <p class="bottom-top">Rounded bottom, top</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #F2EA01;
}

.rounded-edges {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background: black;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.circle-shape {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background: black;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.top-bottom {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background: black;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px 0px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bottom-top {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background: black;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 0px 25px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: what's the HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add `display: flex;` to the div containing all the shapes. it works even with 1 letter

Answer (score 1):

Just change your text in circle

before: `<p class="circle-shape">Circle Shape</p>`

After: `<p class="circle-shape">Rounded Circle Shape</p>`

Answer (score 1):

Use display flex on "div" and remove width from .bottom-top, .top-bottom, .circle-shap & .rounded-edges

Answer (score 1):

Add display: flex; to the div, to make all the elements display in a horizontal line.